# How to translate "consists of" into an EMF model?

Tags: eclipse, model, uml, eclipse-emf-ecore, emf

I specified a model, by writing it down:

> A consists of B. Each B has a name and points. In B there is C
>   assigned if its points are not fulfilled.

How to translate this example into emf?

**UPDATE**

Ok I tried a solution:

A is a class and is connected with B which has as an attribute a name and points. However, I really do not have an idea right now how to handle C?

Comment: Can you explain your model more? Can you try mocking up a set of interfaces in java that describes it and then use emf annotations to generate a genmodel?

Comment: Sorry, I really cannot specify it more, it's rather abstract, but thats the problem for me to translate it into an emf model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between A and B you definitely have an association. Since you emphasize the "consists of", it might be it's a 1:1 *composite aggregate* (i.e. the lifetimes of A and B are coupled).

B has an association to C. Here it sounds like a 0:1 multiplicity. The condition "if .. fulfilled" can't be captured in the static class diagram, since it describes the dynamic behaviour of the system (hence the lower bound 0 above, so that you can use `null`). It isn't directly clear if points are objects (reference) or a number (attribute).

[image: Pic courtesy of yuml.me]
<sub>(source: [yuml.me](https://yuml.me/072e505b.jpg))</sub>

That's how I'd do it (via [Yuml.me](https://yuml.me/)).

As an alternative (depending on the rest of the model), you might find that B actually extends A.

Comment: As @ShiDoiSi said, the dynamic condition that C changes depending on the points cannot be specified directly in a class diagram. For this you can use comments or OCL